# How to pass string to macro function

Tags: c++

I'm using [this](https://github.com/CogentEmbedded/embed-resource/tree/cpp_11_compatibility) lib to embed some resource files into an executable.

The resources can be accessed by the macro function [LOAD_RESOURCE](https://github.com/CogentEmbedded/embed-resource/blob/cpp_11_compatibility/Resource.h#L21-L24).

The resources I want to embed:

- resource/my_resource1.xml
- resource/my_resource2.xml
- resource/type1/my_resource3.xml
- resource/type1/my_resource4.xml
- resource/type2/my_resource3.xml
- resource/type2/my_resource4.xml
- ...

Loading the common resources is easy:

```
 Resource res1 = LOAD_RESOURCE(resource_my_resource1_xml);
 Resource res2 = LOAD_RESOURCE(resource_my_resource2_xml);
```

My problem is that I only know the `type` at runtime, so how can I load resources 3 and 4?

My current solution is through a switch case:

```
Resource res3, res4;
switch (type)
{
    default:
    case 1:
        res3 = LOAD_RESOURCE(resource_type1_my_resource3_xml);
        res4 = LOAD_RESOURCE(resource_type1_my_resource4_xml);
        break;
    case 2:
        res3 = LOAD_RESOURCE(resource_type2_my_resource3_xml);
        res4 = LOAD_RESOURCE(resource_type2_my_resource4_xml);
        break;
}
```

However, this isn't very efficient nor pretty when I have N types and N resources for each.

Is there a better alternative? Can I somehow pass a string to the macro function as the argument? Something like `LOAD_RESOURCE("resource_type" + type + "_my_resourceN_xml")`?

Comment: The preprocessor runs before any code is evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I somehow pass a string to the macro function as the argument?

No you cannot. Macros are expanded by the preprocessor before the compiler actually gets to see the code. In a nutshell, macros are about textual replacment not more.

> My problem is that I only know the type at runtime, so how can I load resources 3 and 4?

I don't know the library, but the `Resource` is merely a pointer to data and a data length. "Loading" a resource does not more than providing you a handle to it. Hence I would load all resoures on program start and then access them at runtime as needed.

For the sake of the example, lets say this is the library code

```
#define LOAD_RESOURCE(path) ([](){ return Resource{}; })()
struct Resource {};
```

Then I would perhaps use this:

```
#include <map>
#include <utility>

using key = std::pair<int,int>;
std::map<key,Resource> load_all_resources(){
    return { 
        { {1,1} , LOAD_RESOURCE(resource_type1_my_resource1_xml) },
        { {1,2} , LOAD_RESOURCE(resource_type1_my_resource2_xml) }
    };
}
int main (){
    auto resources = load_all_resources();
    auto type = 1;
    auto res1 = resources[{type,1}];
}
```

To make the loading more copy-paste friendly one can use a macro

```
#define MY_LOAD_RESOURCE(type,N) { {type,N}, LOAD_RESOURCE( resource_type##type##_my_resource##N_xml )}
```

such that

```
std::map<key,Resource> load_all_resources(){
    return { 
        MY_LOAD_RESOURCE(1,1),
        MY_LOAD_RESOURCE(1,2),
    };
}
```

expands to the same as above. [Complete example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/USe5II4r8H0HJc8P).